# how to create url of image inside the app using swift

Tags: ios, swift, url, photo, gcdwebserver

I hv a small app which shows iPhones videos and images in the app.
Now when I access any photo  or video, I want to generate its http url using GCDWebServer (e.g. http://my-device.local/photo-12-2019.jpg)

I came across this link (https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer)
which to some extent clears concept but not sure how to exactly convert photo or video to url.
I want to expose url to GCDWebServer on my iPhone.
Any sample code or reference would be good.

Thanks